# Xamarin.iOS: Custom view appears multiple times on top of each other for every time I open the app

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, custom-controls, custom-view

I have a simple custom control that consists of a single element UIPickerView.

```
[Register("CustomPicker")]
public class CustomPicker : UIView, IComponent
{
    public CustomPicker(IntPtr p) : base(p)
    {
    }

    public ISite Site { get; set; }

    public event EventHandler Disposed;

    public override void Draw(CGRect rect)
    {
        base.Draw(rect);

        using (var g = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext())
        {
            var label = new UIPickerView(new CGRect(rect.X, rect.Y, rect.Width, rect.Height));
            label.Model = new PeopleModel();
            AddSubview(label);
        }
    }
}
```

I have this simple storyboard:

[image: First time I open the app]

Then for every time I let the app go in background (not terminating) and open it again I get one for picker put on top of the existing, like this:

[image: Second time I open the app]

Any ideas what I do wrong here? Is there a specific way to "remove" a view when app goes in background?

Comment: Here is a link to the project:

https://github.com/mrbassir/customview-test

Comment: Sorry I can't reproduce the issue with your project. You project works well on my side, can you check it again?

Comment: I can still see the issue. Try a couple of times reopening the app, eventually it will go into this state

Comment: Run the project, press home button(app go to background), then reopen it, right?

Comment: Yes, and between the reopenings try to scroll in the picker

Comment: No, I can't see the issue. I run it on the simulator with iOS 12. Are you running the same project in the Github? Actually, go to background and go back to app will only trigger the method like `DidEnterBackground` and `WillEnterForeground`.

Comment: I have now tried with iOS 12 and it seems that the issue is not there. I only see it on iOS 13. That is weird

Comment: Yes, it's weird, I guess it may caused by the iOS 13. I will test it later and update you if I found anything.